# How do you read a specific line of a text file in Python?

Tags: python, line

I'm having trouble reading an entire specific line of a text file using Python. I currently have this:

```
load_profile = open('users/file.txt', "r")
read_it = load_profile.readline(1)
print read_it
```

Of course this will just read one byte of the first line, which is not what I want. I also tried Google but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What are the conditions of this line?  Is it at a certain index?  Does it contain a certain string?  Does it match a regex?

This code will match a single line from the file based on a string:

```
load_profile = open('users/file.txt', "r")
read_it = load_profile.read()
myLine = ""
for line in read_it.splitlines():
    if line == "This is the line I am looking for":
        myLine = line
        break
print myLine
```

And this will give you the first line of the file (there are several other ways to do this as well):

```
load_profile = open('users/file.txt', "r")
read_it = load_profile.read().splitlines()[0]
print read_it
```

Or:

```
load_profile = open('users/file.txt', "r")
read_it = load_profile.readline()
print read_it
```

---

Check out [Python File Objects Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects)

> **file.readline([size])**
>
> Read one entire line from the file. A trailing
>   newline character is kept in the string (but may be absent when a file
>   ends with an incomplete line). [6] If the size argument is present and
>   non-negative, it is a maximum byte count (including the trailing
>   newline) and an incomplete line may be returned. When size is not 0,
>   an empty string is returned only when EOF is encountered immediately.
>
> Note Unlike stdio‘s fgets(), the returned string contains null
>   characters ('\0') if they occurred in the input.
>
> **file.readlines([sizehint])**
>
> Read until EOF using readline() and return
>   a list containing the lines thus read. If the optional sizehint
>   argument is present, instead of reading up to EOF, whole lines
>   totalling approximately sizehint bytes (possibly after rounding up to
>   an internal buffer size) are read. Objects implementing a file-like
>   interface may choose to ignore sizehint if it cannot be implemented,
>   or cannot be implemented efficiently.

---

### Edit:

Answer to your comment Noah:

```
load_profile = open('users/file.txt', "r")
read_it = load_profile.read()
myLines = []
for line in read_it.splitlines():
    # if line.startswith("Start of line..."):
    # if line.endswith("...line End."):
    # if line.find("SUBSTRING") > -1:
    if line == "This is the line I am looking for":
        myLines.append(line)
print myLines
```

Comment: Anytime Noah!  Happy to help.

Comment: What if I have some lines that have the same text on them?

Comment: I would reverse the order of your three examples, +1 for all the detail anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Python's inbuilt module linecache

```
  import linecache
  line = linecache.getline(filepath,linenumber)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
load_profile.readline(1)
```

specifically says to cap at `1` byte.  it doesn't mean `1` line.  Try

```
read_it = load_profile.readline()
```

Comment: This will only read the first line. I need to read a specific line that is NOT the first line.

Comment: @NoahRainey your statement was "Of course this will just read one byte of the first line, which is not what I want.".  And the reason why it's only reading one byte of the first line is because `readline(n)` means read the next line, up to `n` characters.  You should just call `readline()` `n-1` times and then capture the result of readline

Answer (score 1):

```
def readline_number_x(file,x):
    for index,line in enumerate(iter(file)):
        if index+1 == x: return line

    return None

f = open('filename')
x = 3
line_number_x = readline_number_x(f,x) #This will return the third line
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to read an specific line by making a list out of the text, and asking what is the "n-th" element of the list.

```
with open('filename') as xp:
    texto=xp.read() #This makes a string out of the text
    listexto=texto.splitlines() #This makes a list out of the string, making
                                #every element of the list equal to each line
                                #in the string.
    print(listexto[8]) #This prints the eight element of the list.
```