# How to extract rows ( that contain a specific character ) from a text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file like this:

```
aaa:bbb:ccc:dd:ooo
fff:ggg:sddfg:sfsf:s8fsdf
fsdfsd:ghfgh:fsdd:bbf:tyuter:fgdfg
dfgdjrth:hdfg:HDfgsdjtyerER:Ghdrsg:Hdsg8hdd:ssfd
```

and I need a way to extract only the rows that contains the number 8.
In that case, the output should be this:

```
fff:ggg:sddfg:sfsf:s8fsdf
dfgdjrth:hdfg:HDfgsdjtyerER:Ghdrsg:Hdsg8hdd:ssfd
```

Is there a way to do that in python?

Comment: This will almost certainly be a duplicate question, but here's a quick example in 1 line: `[line for line in open(file, 'r') if '8' in line]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you read a specific line of a text file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523001/how-do-you-read-a-specific-line-of-a-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
with open ('test.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
    for myline in myfile:
        if "8" in myline:
            print(myline.rstrip("\n"))
```

All you need to do is check if a line has `"8"` in it. I used an if statement for this. If it does, then print it.

The function of `myline.rstrip("\n")` is to remove the `\n` at the end. **Without** it, this is your output:

```
fff:ggg:sddfg:sfsf:s8fsdf

dfgdjrth:hdfg:HDfgsdjtyerER:Ghdrsg:Hdsg8hdd:ssfd
```

However, **with** it, this is your output, which I think is what you wanted:

```
fff:ggg:sddfg:sfsf:s8fsdf
dfgdjrth:hdfg:HDfgsdjtyerER:Ghdrsg:Hdsg8hdd:ssfd
```

Answer (score 1):

lines = open(file,"r")
for line in lines:
if "8" in line:
print(line)

not as short or optimised as the previous one, but better understandable ;)

```
lines =  ["aaa:bbb:ccc:dd:ooo",
"fff:ggg:sddfg:sfsf:s8fsdf",
"fsdfsd:ghfgh:fsdd:bbf:tyuter:fgdfg",
"dfgdjrth:hdfg:HDfgsdjtyerER:Ghdrsg:Hdsg8hdd:ssfd"]
for line in line:
    if "8" in line:
        print(line)
```

in your case `lines = open(file,"r)`

gives

```
fff:ggg:sddfg:sfsf:s8fsdf
dfgdjrth:hdfg:HDfgsdjtyerER:Ghdrsg:Hdsg8hdd:ssfd
```